# UITableView and didSelectRowAtIndexPath issue

Tags: iphone

I have a UITableView populated with a location-based datasource.  I'm calling [self updateView]; to manually refresh the view after the location is found which works fine...but for some reason the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method isn't getting called.  Any ideas of why it's not working?

Code snippet: http://pastie.org/464300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the delegate property of your tableView is set.

**slf said:**

> Make sure it's defined in your .h
>   file. The protocol does a
>   'doesRespondToSelector' first and if
>   you aren't making it public through
>   your header the message my fail

*-respondsToSelector:* will detect methods that are not exposed in the interface.

Comment: adding:
self.tableView.delegate = self; 

did the trick...thanks!

Comment: good call Red, sorry for the confusion jzting, I voted to delete my post, next time I'll read more before I post